# Is there anywhere where I can get Ubuntu installed for me?

Tags: lenovo

I have tried for days to install Ubuntu on my lenovo ideapad z510 and I feel like giving up. I really feel like I will like Ubuntu, but for some reason I always have some king of problem.

I really don't want to give up on Ubuntu, but I don't want to brick my laptop either.

Is there anywhere I can have Ubuntu installed for me?

I have tried messing with my bios, used a DVD and a USB, but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I am based in Warwick, RI in the USA.
I don't want to run Ubuntu in windows.

Edit 2: I will try the suggestion of going to a local shop or best buy. I will edit again if I find this successful. This may take some time because I need to find time to make the visit.

Comment: Look for Linux User Groups near you. One of the members might be willing to help you out or recommend a shop.

Comment: Where are you based?

Comment: what error(s) are you running into? if there is a specific message, pls include it; or if no error message, pls provide as much relevant detail as you can.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most any local computer shop should know how to install Ubuntu. In my opinion you would be better off looking to Google to find a local computer shop.

And if worse comes to worse you could try best buy if its in your area and see if they would do it.

Suggested Google search: Computer shop Warwick, RI

I would look at the reviews for each store and make sure they have a good rep!

Comment: Best Buy? do they really have Ubuntu installation services?

Comment: I updated the answer... I meant i would check if they would... But i would NEVER recommend best buy!

Answer (score 0):

You should try any local computer repair shop, usually the people that work in those places know how to install Ubuntu. If they don't they will probably give directions to a place where someone can do that for you.