# How can I find a local computer repair shop/expert able to help me with Ubuntu?

Tags: community

I have a cousin that wants to switch away from Microsoft, but she is early 70's, not particularly computer literate. I suggested she had an alternative in Ubuntu, but she wants to see if some computer repair shop can do it for her.

I know from experience that such are rare.  Do you have any sort of referral list of Linux-literate people by locality that might help her?  She's in far northeastern Maine.

Comment: Related: [Is there anywhere where I can get Ubuntu installed for me?](https://askubuntu.com/q/513071/301745)

Comment: There's a few hardware manufacturers that offer Ubuntu preinstalled. Colorado-based System 76 has desktops and laptops with either Ubuntu or their own Pop!_OS. Dell used to have option for Ubuntu, not sure what they do now, though.  Repair shops supporting Linux are not very common and you have to call around or check shop's website to know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a shopping recommendation, thus off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks awfully, guys. I wasn't asking about a shop that could do it for her, I was asking for a referral to someone local that could guide her.  The guy that introduced me to Ubuntu said, "You will have support forever."